# Flex unrecognized rule

Tags: c, parsing, flex-lexer

I'm writing a parser for a simple language, and I'm having some weird trouble with flex. When I try to compile the source over here(http://pastebin.com/qu7N0H3q), I get an "Unrecognized rule" error for lines 50-52, but the weird thing is that they're comments(and should simply be skipped). Until adding the COMMENT conditional everything worked well, so I'm pretty sure that's what breaks everything (line 48 and lines 86-96). I've looked up the issue, couldn't find anything fitting my particular case, but I found that Unrecognized rule errors usually come up when there are syntax issues (might be the case, since I'm not 100% comfortable with how conditional compilation works for flex).

Can anyone please help me figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

This has lain unanswered for a few months, so I thought it needed closure.

I've downloaded your code from pastebin and checked it for you. You actually have the answer in your question! The problem came when you added the COMMENT...

Flex does not have a notation for comments, so you cannot have any, and thus they are "Unrecognised rules".

The solution is to either:

- delete the comments
- Embed the comments in the action parts which will be processed by the compiler and not flex.

I see you used a comment in the syntax for **C**, but you started them in the first column of a line. Only regular expression patterns can start in column one. Anything indented in the page is regarded as part of an action and is copied unchanged. Thus, if you just indented the comment by a few spaces the error would go.

Don't be mislead by the fact that flex allow you to write actions in **C** that you can use artifacts from the **C** language wherever you want!

This is a common mistake made by novice users of flex (or lex) and worthy of being explained in this detailed answer.